# JPanel and JFreeChart error

Tags: java

I am trying to include a JFreeChart into a new JPanel and then refresh my JFrame with the new JPanel when i click a button.Unfortunately, I think there is an error in my program because when I click on the button it just refresh the old JFrame and a red-colored text updates in black.

Here is my code :

My LRTChart class which is supposed to generate the chart

```
class LRTChart
{
    JButton returnButton = new JButton("");

    public void chartCreator(double[] values, int[] days)
    {
         JPanel chart = chartPanel(values, days);
         JPanel  chartPanel= new JPanel();

         Font buttonFont = new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 15);
         returnButton.setFont(buttonFont);
         Box subMenu = Box.createVerticalBox();
         subMenu.add(returnButton);
         chartPanel.add(chart, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         chartPanel.add(subMenu, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

         MainWindow.setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset(double[] values, int[] days)
    {
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeries generalAxis = new XYSeries("x");
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            generalAxis.add(days[i],values[i]);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(generalAxis);
        return dataset;
    }

    private JPanel chartPanel(double[] values, int[] days)
    {
    String chartTitle = "xxx";
        String xAxisLabel = "x";
        String yAxisLabel = "y";

        XYDataset dataset = createDataset(values, days);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(chartTitle, xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, dataset);
        return new ChartPanel(chart);
    }
}
```

The `setContentPane()` method I use :

```
public static void setContentPane(JPanel panel)
{
    JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) window.getContentPane();
    contentPane.removeAll();
    contentPane.add(panel);
    contentPane.revalidate(); 
    contentPane.repaint();
}
```

I Thank all the people that are going to help me.

Comment: You can refresh the view by calling SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(contentPane);

Comment: This is not the problem, when i click the button it does nothing but refresh the current JPanel instead of showing the new one with the chart